# Paginação com Jquery

Tags: jquery, paginação

Pesquisei em alguns sites e aqui no stack à procura de como criar um script de paginação com as seguintes características:

- Os elementos são coletados no próprio `HTML`
- Posso usar a função a qualquer momento e em qualquer elemento, apenas invocando-a e passando os parâmetros (tais como, número de elementos por página, qual elemento deve ser paginado, qual o elemento pai da paginação, etc)

No caso, não encontrei nenhuma pergunta/resposta que conseguisse esclarecer por completo esses pontos, também não encontrei uma boa `API`, tentei o `easyPaginate`, porém ele está gerando erros no `jquery` ao ser usado.
Alguma sugestão de `API` ou `script` para essa paginação ?

```
    <div id="pagination">
        <div>
            <figure></figure>
            <figure></figure>
            <figure></figure>
            <figure></figure>
            <figure></figure>
            <figure></figure>
            <figure></figure>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Um script que possa ser usado de forma simples, como o próprio easyPaginate que citei acima

```
$("#pagination").paginar({
   elemento:figure,
   elementosporpagina:3
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use os elemento dessa forma

```
<div id="pagination">
            <figure><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/50/"></figure>
            <figure><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/50/"></figure>
            <figure><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/50/"></figure>
            <figure><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/50/"></figure>
            <figure><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/50/"></figure>
            <figure><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/50/"></figure>
            <figure><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/50/"></figure>
    </div>
```

[Jquery.paginate](http://github.com/neighbordog/jquery-paginate)

Após linkar a biblioteca (js e css), adicione

```
$('#pagination').paginate({ 'perPage': 5 });
$('#pagination').paginate({ 'scope': $('figure') });
```