# Como implementar paginação no script JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

Estou utilizando JQuery em minha aplicação de filtro com selects e gostaria se saber como implementar uma paginação.

**HTML**

```
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#frm_buscar_imoveis_rotemix').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formDados = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        var formnegocio = document.forms.tar.negocio.value;
        var formcidade = document.forms.tar.cidade.value;
        var formtipo = document.forms.tar.tipo.value;
        var formvalores = document.forms.tar.valores.value;

        $.ajax({
            url:'resultado.php?negocio='+formnegocio+'&cidade='+formcidade+'&tipo='+formtipo+'&valores='+formvalores+'',
            type:'GET',
            data:formDados,
            cache:false,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend: function () {
        $("#resultado").html("<div class='cssload-spin-barra'><div class='cssload-spin-box'></div></div>");
        //$("#demo").fadeOut(0).html(result).fadeIn(500);
    },
            success:function (data)
     {$('#resultado').html(data);
             /* $('#envia_msg_copia_02').each (function(){
            this.reset();
           }); */
      },
            dataType:'html'
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$gv_noticias=mysqli_query($con,"

        SELECT
        titulo
        FROM
        imoveis
        WHERE
        venda = 2

        ");

while($noticias_guarapari=mysqli_fetch_array($gv_noticias))
    {
echo $noticias_guarapari['titulo'];
    }
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Paginação com Jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243367/pagina%c3%a7%c3%a3o-com-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

```js
    function paginate(array, page_size, page_number) {
          return array.slice((page_number - 1) * page_size, page_number * page_size);
    }

    const array = [{ titulo: "Julio" }, { titulo: "Giuliano" }]

    console.log(paginate(array, 1, 1))
```

use o php para retornar todas as linhas da sua tabela. e no javascript implemente a função de paginação

seu array de objetos:

```
const array = [{ titulo: "Julio" }, { titulo: "Giuliano" }]
função de paginação
```

função de paginação `javascript`

```
function paginate(array, page_size, page_number) {
  return array.slice((page_number - 1) * page_size, page_number * page_size);
}
```

onde page_size é o tamanho do array que você quer mostrar (1, 2, 100 etc) e page_number é o número em que vc vai estar. ex se o array tem 100 itens e você colocou um tamanho de 50, se seu page number for 1, você vai acessar os 50 primeiros itens, se for 2 será os 50 seguintes itens.